# Cross compiling kernel version 4.16.3 with ARCH variable set to "x86_64" throws error missing separator -- Make

Tags: c, linux, makefile, kernel

I am compiling linux which cause error with command

```
 make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE=name_unknown
```

error

```
CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  CHK     include/generated/bounds.h
  CHK     include/generated/timeconst.h
  CHK     include/generated/asm-offsets.h
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  DESCEND  objtool
/home/ubuntu/new/source1/linux-4.16.3/tools/objtool/.fixdep.o.cmd:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
make[3]: *** [Makefile:43: /home/ubuntu/new/source1/linux-4.16.3/tools/objtool/fixdep-in.o] Error 2
make[2]: *** [/home/ubuntu/new/source1/linux-4.16.3/tools/build/Makefile.include:4: fixdep] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:63: objtool] Error 2
```

I like to know, which makefile in which make found line with missing tab `\t` separator

ofcourse the makefile I can not read all so I like to know what this line tells `/home/ubuntu/new/source1/linux-4.16.3/tools/objtool/.fixdep.o.cmd:1: ***...`

or

`*** [/home/ubuntu/new/source1/linux-4.16.3/tools/build/Makefile.include:4: fixdep] Error 2`

or

`*** [Makefile:63: objtool] Error 2`

where it found space or something in place of tab. which makefile. is it at the root of source -- which obviously very big. So I like to pinpoint to the line which is wrongly typed.

or makefile in folder `/home/ubuntu/new/source1/linux-4.16.3/tools/objtool/` which also contains Makefile in it

or is it `[/home/ubuntu/new/source1/linux-4.16.3/tools/build/Makefile.include:4`

so question is how to understand make error message like missing separator into what file actually causing the problem.

Without it I can not find any success in compiling this kernel version

Also how is it possible that what available in kernel source link can made this simple mistake (something in place of tab?how is it possible) Or I am missing something

Comment: make file at the root of source has no line. just comment starting with`#` in line 43 48 and 63. So its not in the source root makefile. Which other make file is it showinng in error message?

Comment: The output presented is not conclusive, but it looks like you are looking for line 43 of `/home/ubuntu/new/source1/linux-4.16.3/tools/objtool/Makefile`.  Since `make` seems to be reporting that the actual error is in `.fixdep.o.cmd`, I would be inclined to guess that the makefile is `include`ing that file.